# Photo identity card generation API for java

Tags: java, api, photo

I am developing a small scale patient record program. One of the functionalities they need is to generate [Photo ID Card](http://www.google.com/imgres?um=1&hl=en&rlz=1C1CHMR_enBD462BD462&biw=1280&bih=933&tbm=isch&tbnid=ZUiN09zYNYAAwM%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.smartcardsindia.in/id.html&docid=EwnKSfjZY_dDbM&imgurl=http://www.smartcardsindia.in/img/id_card2_wideweb__430x315.jpg&w=430&h=315&ei=4vBAT5rnKM7LrQf8oszbBw&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=340&vpy=299&dur=4676&hovh=192&hovw=262&tx=158&ty=118&sig=104252611515509359507&page=1&tbnh=116&tbnw=159&start=0&ndsp=30&ved=0CGAQrQMwBw) by fetching a bunch of rows from the DB. I have very little experience in jasper reports. I am looking for a API which can help generate these ID cards. For example I will feed the API a design template and a the data result set and it will do the job. 
If you are suggesting jasper and iReport then please guide me through the process of solving the problem. and if there are no API then can you please show me a way where i can achieve similar result?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was solved using jasper reports itself. I just had to set up a proper layout for a single ID. Now this is important only 1 layout is needed to be designed. And then you need to specify a query that will return the list of rows to be used to generate the ID cards.

Your query will return multiple rows so you need them arranged one after another, its so common that you want 8ID cards in 1 A4 page (2columns). For this case right click the report -> properties set columns to 2 and print order horizontal. Make sure your model stays within a single column